# How to set classloader for XMLDecoder?

Tags: java, classloader

I have a small program which uses plugins. I am using Java's built in X`MLDecoder/Encoder` system to save data files for this program. The snag I'm having is that when I go to load these files using the `XMLDecoder`, I get a message stating, that the `class is not in the classpath.`

Essentially what I have is a classloader for each plugin and during normal execution, those class loaders create new instances of those classes. So my question is, how can I easily supply these urls containing the classpaths to the `XMLDecoder` class loader?

Thank you for the help,

Jec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some cases, you can just pass the ClassLoader of the calling class when you instantiate XMLDecoder.

```
XMLDecoder decoder = new XMLDecoder(in, null, null, this.getClass().getClassLoader());
```